# NS2: simulating nodes running two different mac protocol

Tags: objective-c, ns2

I wanted to simulate nodes, running different mac protocols  so that they can co exist/ transfer packet b/n each other with out causing any problem on each other..how can I do that...especially how can I modify simple wireless simulation code

example if macs are like 
1. set val(mac1) Mac/802_3 ;# MAC type just example 
2.set val(mac2) Mac/802_11 ;# the other mac protocol

JUST POINT OUT WHERE/HOW SHALL I MODIFY THE CODE

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use two mac protocols like mentioned above.. for example if like to merge two mac protocols (mac 802.11 and mac csma) you have to create a new protocol (say mac merge) in **merge.cc** you have to write your own mechanism. then u can call **set val(mac1) Mac/Merge** from your tcl.. the only thing here is you have to mention at what condition 802.11 or csma will work...